# JavaScript create table on button click on another page

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am very new to JavaScript. I have two HTML pages productquantity.html and checkout.html. Now I want to create table with some data on button click from productquantity.html and display the table on checkout.html

JavaScript code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
   <!-- Begin  
     function  doMath() {  
        int = "2000"
        var one = eval(int) 
        var two = eval(document.theForm.elements[0].value)    
        var prod = one  *   two    

        document.getElementById("showsum").innerHTML = ( prod );
     }
   // End -->  
</SCRIPT>
```

html code:

```
<FORM NAME="theForm" action="display.html" method="GET">  
   <INPUT TYPE="text">  
   <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Show result" onClick="doMath()">

   <div id="showsum"> </div>
</FORM>
```

At the moment its showing result on same page but I want to display result on another page in table when submit button is clicked.

Comment: a fiddle will be appreciated

Comment: Your code works ok. what table do you want?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/umerk/3gFCc/3/) here is the link to fiddle i dont know its not showing sum of product on fiddle but its working fine  here with me. and at the moment its showing result on same page but i want to diplay result on another page in table

Comment: @MarsOne yes i want to display the result in table on another page (checkout.html)

Comment: With your actual markup and script it's impossible to show up the result on site checkout.html. But you could display the table on the same site.

Comment: A bit off-topic but instead of `evan(int)`, use `parseInt(int, 10)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Not sure if this solves your original problem, but here is the fixed version of the fiddle, that actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/3gFCc/4/

Comment: If the data is dynamic, you'll need to write it in session/cookie before you redirect to next page. I have never done this with just javascript so I can't help you with actual example. And btw, you don't need to have your markup all caps, this is long gone. Also, if you're planning on using javascript a lot, you should consider learning jQuery as it's more simple and much faster to work with.

Comment: @bvukelic thanks for your tips and for the better version of fiddle

Comment: @maremp yes you are right sessions/cookie will do the job done but question is how? and thanks for fine tips

Comment: but can anyone help me creating the table with result on samepage???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load something from a file to another you should use ajax (I suggest using jQuery for this).

```
$('#result').load('productquantity.html ', function() {
  alert('The other page is loaded');
});
```